# Remove SelectedItems from a ListBox via MVVM RelayCommand

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a list of items in a WPF ListBox. I want to allow the user to select several of these items and click a Remove button to eliminate these items from the list.

Using the MVVM RelayCommand pattern, I've created a command with the following signature:

```
public RelayCommand<IList> RemoveTagsCommand { get; private set; }
```

In my View, I wire up my RemoveTagsCommand like this:

```
<DockPanel>
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Command="{Binding RemoveTagsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TagList, Path=SelectedItems}">Remove tags</Button>
<ListBox x:Name="TagList" ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:Tag}">
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

My ViewModel constructor sets up an instance of the command:

```
RemoveTagsCommand = new RelayCommand<IList>(RemoveTags, CanRemoveTags);
```

My current implementation of RemoveTags feels clunky, with casts and copying. Is there a better way to implement this?

```
    public void RemoveTags(IList toRemove)
    {
        var collection = toRemove.Cast<Tag>();
        List<Tag> copy = new List<Tag>(collection);

        foreach (Tag tag in copy)
        {
            Tags.Remove(tag);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks fairly clean to me, though you might be able to bind `SelectedItems` to a property on your VM using `Mode=OneWayToSource` and then use the bound collection property from `RemoveTags`.
 I'm not entirely sure, but you may be able to use a strongly-typed IList collection in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use a strongly typed IList. I think this is a limitation of the SelectedItemCollection returned by WPF, but it could also be due to the particular flavor of RelayCommand I use.

Comment: Looking at this again, I see the real concern is that the SelectedItems list may change as a result of the removal, which is why you create the copy.  If that's the case, I think this code is about as clean as you'll get.  The casting is unavoidable, unless you want to make your RelayCommand support the casting internally (something like `RelayListCommand<Tag>` with an implicit `Cast<T>` adapting `IList` to `IList<T>`).

Comment: Thanks, Dan. You're right -- the copying and casting feels a bit clunky, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I am using Prism DelegateCommand<T> though it is also not supporting new DelegateCommand<IList<MyClss>>(Action). Interestingly it has the support for DelegateCommand<T>

Answer (score 4):

I'd use the `ItemContainerStyle` on the `ListBox` to bind the items' `IsSelected` property to a flag in the Model (not View Model), e.g.:

```
 <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">  
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>  
    </Style> 
 </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Then you don't need to worry about what argument you're passing in to your command.  Also, in my experience when it's simple for an object in a view model to know that the user selected it, you find other uses for that information.

The code in the command would be something like:

```
foreach (Tag t in Tags.Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList())
{
   Tags.Remove(t);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. That's a very interesting approach. I'm not sure about letting UI state leak into my ViewModel, though.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me.  The view model is the model of the view.  It seems entirely appropriate for it to know about UI state.  If it exposes a command to remove selected items, surely it should know what the selected items are.  You might restyle your view so that it uses a `ListView` instead of a `ListBox`, but you're not going to restyle it so that it doesn't let the user select the items to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you specify the type argument of the `RelayCommand` to be a `List<Tag>`, since that is what you are going to get anyway? There is no point specifying a more generic type than that because the executed handler is hard-coded to work with a list of `Tag` objects. Since you've already made the dependency there, you might as well make it on the type argument, as well. Then your executed handler won't need any cast or copying.

Comment: I don't believe SelectedItems will be List<Tag>, even though you've only added Tag instances.

Comment: @Dan is right; I can't use a List<Tag> here. I think the SelectedItems property returns a non-generic SelectedItemsCollection object.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Bind your Remove button a Command in your ViewModel.

2.) When you set up your binding, use a CommandParameter to take the Selecteditems from your ListBox by giving your ListBox a name and using ElementName=NameOfListBox, Path=SelectedItems

3.) Make sure your Command in your ViewModel passes along the arguments. You'll get an object that you can cast as an IList.

Below is a simple example, this should help you set up your structure.

In the View:

```
<Button Command="{Binding CommandInViewModelForRemove}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=blah,Path=SelectedItems}"

<ListBox x:Name="blah" .... />
```

In the ViewModel:

```
public ViewModel(){
    RemoveCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(Remove, CanRemove);
}

private void Remove(object selectedItems){
   var list = (IList)selectedItems;
   //do some work, cast to view models that represent list items, etc
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was actually doing the things you suggest already. My question was about the "do some work" bits in your sample. Is there a cleaner, better way to remove items from the list without casting each item and copying the selectedItems to a new list?

Comment: Wow, I completely missed that -- sorry about that! Let me head back to the drawing board and see what I come up with. Cheers!